# Increase or decrease value assigned to a property to make smaller or bigger triangle

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a user control in Visual c# Winforms. What i want is when i click in the control and drag to the left, decrease a value from a property that is directly related with the triangle size, and when i drag to the right i have to increase this value to make the triangle bigger, and show this property value in label2 of another form that i created, here i give a photo that probably will help you. I will appreciate some help. Thank you guys

[Triangle behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyumQ.png)

Here is the code from both files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MisControles
{
    public partial class ControlVolumen: UserControl
    {
        private int valor;
        Color color1;
        Color color2;
        Color color3;
        public int Valor
        {
            get { return valor; }
            set { valor = value; this.Refresh(); }
        }

        public ControlVolumen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            color1 = Color.LawnGreen;
            color2 = Color.Yellow;
            color3 = Color.Red;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(color1);
            Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(color2);
            Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(color3);
            int ancho = this.Width * Valor / 100;
            int alto = this.Height * Valor / 100;
            Point p0 = new Point(0, this.Height);
            Point p1 = new Point(ancho, this.Height);
            Point p2 = new Point(ancho, this.Height - alto);

            if (valor <= 50) {
                g.FillPolygon(b, new Point[] { p0, p1, p2 }); 
            }else if (valor <= 90)
            {
                g.FillPolygon(b1, new Point[] { p0, p1, p2 });
            }else if (valor > 90)
            {
                g.FillPolygon(b2, new Point[] { p0, p1, p2 });
            }

            
        }

    }
}

/* The form with the control */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Volumen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Image img2;
        Image img1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            img1 = Image.FromFile("btn2.png");
            img2 = Image.FromFile("btn1.png");
            this.checkBox1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(img1, new Size(32, 32)));
            label2.Text = "";
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                this.checkBox1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(img1, new Size(32, 32)));
                label1.Text = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                this.checkBox1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(img2, new Size(32, 32)));
                label1.Text = "Mute On";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Interact with the mouse events**

Handle the relevant mouse events to calculate and set the new value according to the mouse position while the left mouse button is pressed. Refresh the painting by calling the `Invalidate()` method.

**Notify the host**

Create a custom event to notify the host whenever the value is changed by calling the `OnValorChanged` event invoker.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MisControles
{
    [DesignerCategory("Code"),
        DefaultEvent("ValorChanged"),
        DefaultProperty("Valor")]
    public class ControlVolumen : Control
    {
        private SolidBrush b1, b2, b3;

        public ControlVolumen () : base()
        {
            SetStyle(
                ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            UpdateStyles();

            b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.LawnGreen);
            b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
            b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        }

        private int valor;
        public int Valor
        {
            get { return valor; }
            set
            {
                valor = value < 0 ? 0 : value > 100 ? 100 : value;
                Invalidate();
                OnValorChanged();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;
            var ancho = Width * Valor / 100;
            var alto = Height * Valor / 100;
            var p0 = new Point(0, Height);
            var p1 = new Point(ancho, Height);
            var p2 = new Point(ancho, Height - alto);
            var b = valor < 50 ? b1 : valor <= 90 ? b2 : b3;

            g.Clear(BackColor);
            g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { p0, p1, p2 });
        }

        // Valor with capital V. The public property not the private field.
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                Valor = GetValorFromPoint(e.Location);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                Valor = GetValorFromPoint(e.Location);
        }

        // Clean up.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                b1.Dispose();
                b2.Dispose();
                b3.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public event EventHandler ValorChanged;

        protected virtual void OnValorChanged() => 
            ValorChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

        // MaximumValue * Point.X / Width
        private int GetValorFromPoint(Point p) => 
            (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * p.X / Width));
    }
}
```

In the hosting Form, double click on the control to subscribe to the default `ValorChanged` event and handle it as follows:

```cs
private void controlVolumen1_ValorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = controlVolumen1.Valor.ToString();
}
```

[image: SOQ65384241]

Also, I think filling the polygon by a [LinearGradientBrush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dm7L.gif) with [ColorBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) is more appropriate for this control.

For example:

```cs
// +
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var ancho = Width * Valor / 100;
    var alto = Height * Valor / 100;
    var p0 = new Point(0, Height);
    var p1 = new Point(ancho, Height);
    var p2 = new Point(ancho, Height - alto);

    g.Clear(BackColor);

    var cb = new ColorBlend
    {
        Colors = new[] { Color.LawnGreen, Color.Yellow, Color.Red },
        Positions = new[] { 0, 0.75f, 1 }
    };

    using (var br = new LinearGradientBrush(
        ClientRectangle, Color.Empty, Color.Empty, 0f))
    {
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, new[] { p0, p1, p2 });
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: SOQ65384241B]

Answer (score 0):

The [`TrackBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/trackbar-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) control feels appropriate to use here. You can use the [`ValueChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged?view=net-5.0) and use its `Value` property to update your label.